# F# PCL and System.IO.FileStream

Tags: f#

I am writing a PCL using F# and I am trying to write something to disk.  All of the PCL examples are in VB.NET and C# and those examples don't work in F#.  Specifically, I have this code:

```
type FileSystemStockProvider(filePath:string) =
    member this.PutData(stockData) =
        let serializedData = stockData 
                                |> Seq.map(fun row -> JsonConvert.SerializeObject(row))
        let outFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filePath)
        outFile.Write(serializedData)
```

The problem is that the System.IO.StreamWriter in F# does not have an overload to disk so it does not compile.  Does anyone have a suggestion on how to write to disk using a PCL?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe I'm not following, but the `StreamWriter` you see in C# is the same in F# (with the same overloads, etc). Your code [compiles fine](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kfCxLz).

Comment: That fiddle is targeting 4.5.  In a PCL, that overload is not available as far as I can tell..

Comment: For Windows Store apps have a look at [`StorageFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirmed, the overload you were looking for is missing.  However, I don't think this is a mistake, as it is missing from the .net framework for C# and F#.  It's not F# specific.  The reason I expect is because of the sand boxing requirement on different mobile and cross platform devices.  So, the Windows / Linux path name which we are used to doesn't apply universally any more.

See https://pclstorage.codeplex.com/.  Use Nuget to retrieve

To reduce the number of steps in getFileStream, probably there is some room to do a little string parsing in a c:\ or a \\networkPath, or even a url based aRootWithAFewReservedWords://the/path/to/the/file.json kind of way.

btw: there was a problem with disposing of the file stream in your code.  You need to be explicit and use one of the use / using / dispose techniques.  Are you definitely not seeing the overload?

```
namespace PortableLibrary1

open Newtonsoft.Json

[<JsonObject>]
type TestType() =
    [<JsonProperty>]
    member val Property2 = "testData" with get, set

type FileSystemStockProvider(filePath:string) =

    //let getFileStream folder file = 
    //    // for windows / linux?
    //    new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\" + folder + "\\" + filePath)   

    let getFileStream folder file = 
         let rootFolder =  PCLStorage.FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage
         let folder = rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync(folder,PCLStorage.CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists).Result
         let file = folder.CreateFileAsync(file, PCLStorage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting).Result
         file.OpenAsync(PCLStorage.FileAccess.ReadAndWrite).Result

    member __.PutData(stockData) =
        let fs = getFileStream "theFolder" "theFile.json"
        use outFile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fs)
        stockData |> Seq.iter (JsonConvert.SerializeObject >> outFile.Write)
```

Comment: you should do some eta-reductions ;) : `stockData |> Seq.iter (JsonConvert.SerializeObject >> outFile.Write)`

Comment: @CarstenKönig: included your suggestion

Comment: Did you do this in a PCL?

Comment: @JamieDixon: I made a mistake by using FSI.  A correction is provided above to use PCLStorage.  98% of change is in getFileStream.